# Missing & Failed Folder At/and After Installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, shared-folders

I am new to Linux, and I've trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (dual boot with Windows XP). I choose to add new partition (FAT32 150 GB) for the shared folder. But when I pressed the install button, the installer warned me :

> Failed to create the 150 GB shared partition.

So I turned back to the partition section and changed the shared partition to 50GB FAT32 (/mnt/shared). I pressed the install button and I was successful. But, when I boot Ubuntu, I could not find this 50GB folder.

QUESTIONS:
1. What is wrong with the 150GB size? Is my hard disk failing?
2. Why is the 50GB shared folder not showing?

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a FAT32 volume was once 32 Gigs, but [can be higher depending on](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938432.aspx) the formatting tool. 150GB is probably beyond the limits. You may wish to consider NTFS for your shared partition, since Ubuntu can reliable read and write NTFS in the last several releases.

To help locate your shared partition, please post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: I agree with this. Unless there is a specific reason you need FAT32, I would format the partition to NTFS.